# In angular video is not playing

Tags: angular

I am using Angular 4 and I want to play video.My code is given below

```
    <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/1CYBkEJV7T4" 
    allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

When I am using this it's showing me an error

Error parsing header X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block; report=: insecure reporting URL for secure page at character position 22. The default protections will be applied.
NTEznm0vuzU:1 Error parsing header X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block; report=https://www.google.com/appserve/security-bugs/log/youtube: insecure reporting URL for secure page at character position 22. The default protections will be applied.

please anyone help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a domSanitizer of angular.
In your HTML,

```
<iframe class="embed-responsive-item" [src]="getSafeURL()"></iframe>
```

and in your component's .ts file:

```
//import the needed class.
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

// Add the dependency.
constructor(private _domSanitizer: DomSanitizer){
}
    getSafeURL(){
     return _domService.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(' Your youtube url');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create like the following way.This will work

```
    <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
      <strong>**title**</strong>
    </div>

    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
    <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/JwRTpWZReJk"></iframe>
    </div>
    </div>
```